# MongoDB query with required and optional filters

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to writet a MongoDB query object that would say

1. The resulting documents must be in this range of ids
2. Then further filter with these optional OR parameters

Given a document structure like

```
[
  {
    "_id":"abc1",
    "country":"usa",
    "city":"new york"
  },
  {
    "_id":"abc2",
    "country":"usa",
    "city":"new jersey"
  },
  {
    "_id":"abc3",
    "country":"canada",
    "city":"toronto"
  }
]
```

How can we filter documents that are only of id `abc1/2/3` but can be from `new york` or `new jersey` or `canada`

Here is what I have

```
{
  "$and":[
    {
      "_id":{
        "$in":["abc1","abc2", "abc3" ]
      },
      {
        "$or":[
          {"city":"new york"},
          {"city":"new jersey"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "$or":[
          {"country":"canada"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But when I include a "canada" instead of "usa" I get no results back. If

Comment: In your collection `canada` field is `location` but in your query is `country`. By the way, is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GRjN7SjR6s1) what are you looking for?

Comment: Ah sorry, pretend data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  "$and":[
    {
      "_id":{
        "$in":["abc1","abc2", "abc3" ]
      },
      {
        "$or":[
          {"city":{"$in":["new jersey","new york"]}},
          {"country":"canada"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```